# webkitspeechrecognition - put in "period" instead of the punctuation "."

Tags: javascript, webkitspeechrecognition

My implementation of `webkitspeechrecognition` stopped picking up command words (i.e. period, comma, new line) starting this week (Jan 15th, 2023).

I used the implementation from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html for the past 5 years and never had a punctuation problem. However, what is weird is that the demo page still works. But, it will break when I download the source code and try running on my own server.

My guess is my domain is not "registered"/"whitelisted"?

Comment: I just tested the same thing and I'm getting the same result as you. I have also been using the same code for the last many years, and have also replicated what you're saying. The same exact code "corrects" punctuation on google.com but not on other domains!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being tracked as [Chromium bug 1408253](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1408253). Hopefully we'll see a fix for this soon.